# Query values from single column and fill columns, both based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to query solely the IDs of clients that meet specific criteria from a source tab to an output tab and fill 2 columns with static values and 2 columns with dynamic values, based on criteria.

In the source tab I have:

```
+-----------------------+------+
| Status                | ID   |
+-----------------------+------+
| Retired/Deceased      | 2a33 |
+-----------------------+------+
| Liquidation           | 1sTR |
+-----------------------+------+
| Dissolved             | 3B76 |
+-----------------------+------+
| Released from company | 463z |
+-----------------------+------+
| Active                | 557g |
+-----------------------+------+
| In progress           | zz34 |
+-----------------------+------+
| Demo                  | cc56 |
+-----------------------+------+
```

**Please note, that there are 7 criteria values and I need the output for only 4 of them. Meaning that I need 4 values, based on which there will be binary fill of dynamic columns. The other 3 values are obsolete.**

**From these 4 values, if I have eg. Criteria 1, then I will have one fill of the 2 dynamic columns, if not (for the other 3 values) I will have other fill values.**

So I guess simply going with a binary solution for the selection of the specific values is not applicable.

In the output tab logic:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   Output tab                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | Status | Reason | Comment                    | Detail                     |
+----+--------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| A1 | Static | Static | If criteria = criteria 1,  | If criteria = criteria 1,  |
|    |        |        |    then null,              |    then value 1,           |
|    |        |        |    else criteria value     |    else value 2            |
+----+--------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| B1 | Static | Static | If criteria = criteria 1,  | If criteria = criteria 1,  |
|    |        |        |    then null,              |    then value 1,           |
|    |        |        |    else criteria value     |    else value 2            |
+----+--------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| C1 | Static | Static | If criteria = criteria 1,  | If criteria = criteria 1,  |
|    |        |        |    then null, else         |    then value 1,           |
|    |        |        |    criteria value          |    else value 2            |
+----+--------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| D1 | Static | Static | If criteria = criteria 1,  | If criteria = criteria 1,  |
|    |        |        |    then null,              |    then value 1,           |
|    |        |        |    else criteria value     |    else value 2            |
+----+--------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| E1 | Static | Static | If criteria = criteria 1,  | If criteria = criteria 1,  |
|    |        |        |    then null,              |    then value 1,           |
|    |        |        |    else criteria value     |    else value 2            |
+----+--------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| F1 | Static | Static | If criteria = criteria 1,  | If criteria = criteria 1,  |
|    |        |        |    then null,              |    then value 1,           |
|    |        |        |    else criteria value     |    else value 2            |
+----+--------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| G1 | Static | Static | If criteria = criteria 1,  | If criteria = criteria 1,  |
|    |        |        |    then null,              |    then value 1,           |
|    |        |        |    else criteria value     |    else value 2            |
+----+--------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Dummy output tab:

```
+-----------------------+------+-------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
| Status                | ID   | Status            | Reason      | Comment          | Detail                          |
+-----------------------+------+-------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
| Retired/Deceased      | 2a33 | Unable to proceed | Unspecified | Retired/Deceased | Retired/No longer in business   |
+-----------------------+------+-------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
| Liquidation           | 1sTR | Unable to proceed | Unspecified | Liquidation      | Retired/No longer in business   |
+-----------------------+------+-------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
| Dissolved             | 3B76 | Unable to proceed | Unspecified | Dissolved        | Retired/No longer in business   |
+-----------------------+------+-------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
| Released from company | 463z | Unable to proceed | Unspecified | (null)           | No longer works for the company |
+-----------------------+------+-------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
```

**The column 'Status' is not required. I added it just for reference and readability.**

**Apologies, but I have corporate security restrictions for sharing links to Google Sheets.**

The part that I struggle most with is that in column 4 (the first one from the dynamic ones) needs to return the value of the criteria from column 2 from the source tab.

So far I have worked my way around the first part of the query, where I `QUERY` the IDs based on multiple criteria, labelled and filled the static values columns.

```
=QUERY(Data!$A$3:$BN, 
    "SELECT B, 'Unable to proceed', 'Unspecified' 
     WHERE A = 'Retired/Deceased' 
      OR A = ''Liquidation' 
      OR A = 'Dissolved'  
      OR A = 'Released from company' 
      AND A IS NOT NULL
     LABEL 'Unable to proceed' 'Unspecified' , 'Status' 'Reason'", 1)
```

However, I am struggling with the dynamic columns, based on multiple criteria.

I looked up `ARRAYFORMULA` with `IFERROR` and `VLOOKUP` in a nested `QUERY`, but was not able to work my way around it.

Also, I am quite interested in how this would work if there were more than 2 options of values to fill columns 3 and 4 in the output tab.
As far as I know, the way to work around 2 values based on criteria is to nest an `IFERROR` function to make it binary. But what if there were more than 2 values to fill the arrays with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### based on status:

```
=QUERY({QUERY(Data!$A$1:$B, 
        "SELECT B, 'Unable to proceed', 'Unspecified' 
         WHERE A = 'Retired/Deceased' 
            OR A = 'Liquidation' 
            OR A = 'Dissolved'  
            OR A = 'Released from company' 
           AND A IS NOT NULL
         LABEL 'Unable to proceed''Status', 'Unspecified''Reason'", 1),
        QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
        QUERY(Data!$A$2:$B, 
        "SELECT A
         WHERE A = 'Retired/Deceased' 
            OR A = 'Liquidation' 
            OR A = 'Dissolved'  
            OR A = 'Released from company' 
           AND A IS NOT NULL", 0), 
 {"Retired/Deceased",      "Retired/Deceased", "Retired/No longer in business";
  "Liquidation",           "Liquidation",      "Retired/No longer in business";
  "Dissolved",             "Dissolved",        "Retired/No longer in business";
  "Released from company", "",                 "No longer works for the company"}, {2, 3}, 0), )), 
        "LABEL Col1 'Comment', Col2 'Detail'", 0)}, , 0)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

### based on ID:

```
=QUERY({QUERY(Data!$A$1:$B, 
        "SELECT B, 'Unable to proceed', 'Unspecified' 
         WHERE A = 'Retired/Deceased' 
            OR A = 'Liquidation' 
            OR A = 'Dissolved'  
            OR A = 'Released from company' 
           AND A IS NOT NULL
         LABEL 'Unable to proceed''Status', 'Unspecified''Reason'", 1),
        QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
        QUERY(Data!$A$2:$B, 
        "SELECT B
         WHERE A = 'Retired/Deceased' 
            OR A = 'Liquidation' 
            OR A = 'Dissolved'  
            OR A = 'Released from company' 
           AND A IS NOT NULL", 0), 
 {"2a33", "Retired/Deceased", "Retired/No longer in business";
  "1sTR", "Liquidation",      "Retired/No longer in business";
  "3B76", "Dissolved",        "Retired/No longer in business";
  "463z", "",                 "No longer works for the company"}, {2, 3}, 0), )), 
        "LABEL Col1'Comment', Col2'Detail'", 0)}, , 0)
```

[image]